# Loading another page into DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, xampp

Function .load doesn't work on Chrome on localhost (with Xampp). 
On JsFiddle nothing happens if I run the button. My goal is on load to DIV  id="lista_ogol" another page. Is it possible? 
Thanks for every help, if my code is messy let me know what to change.

Here is my html code:

```
<ul>
    <div id="lista_ogol" class="lista">
    <li><a id="rejestracjaID" href="javascript:void(0)" >Rejestracja</a></li>
    <li><a href="logowanie.php">Logowanie</a></li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

Here is my Js script:

```
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#rejestracjaID').click(function(){
                jQuery('#lista_ogol').load('logowanie.php', 
                        function(){alert('Content Successfully Loaded.')} 
                );
            });
        })
```

Comment: Can you please check your console logs and paste here?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` I'm sorry and I will delete this Question if it is too easy. I am just starting with coding

Comment: If below ans works, do not forget to mark it as "Answer"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886614/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Thanks, still the code doesn't work propertly but it doesn't show any warnings. I had included the code in HEAD before, now i have it in body and Chrome finally see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include jquery script in your html file.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you put this in the `<head>` of your document, or above the script you use to load the PHP page.

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't getting any jQuery related errors (like `$ is not defined`/`jQuery is not defined`), it means jQuery is working fine.

The first thing that comes into mind ending up in situations like this is that **the requested page was not found**. Try including the *correct* ***URL*** to the `logowanie.php` (e.g. `"/gate/login/logowanie.php"`) as the `.load()` might not have been able to locate the file that you have requested.

Meanwhile, if you want to add any new html page into the DIV, an alternative (*which may or may not serve your purpose*) is to first echo out an *iframe* and then append it using `.append()` method of jQuery as such:

```
jQuery('#lista_ogol').append(<the iframe>);
```