# Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined error when using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have read this: [Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886614/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined)

Which led me to this: [Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075337/uncaught-referenceerror-is-not-defined)

After understanding the problem that I was not referencing jQuery before I was using it I changed my code.

From this:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

I moved jQuery to the top like this:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

That fixed my first `Uncaught ReferenceError`. I am however still getting the same error but from select2.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js:2
    <anonymous> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js:2
select2.min.js:2:83
```

I do not know how to reference it any sooner and ever [their own page](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) shows how to setup the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I tried to use `select2` in my `base.html` file. I never referenced jQuary there.

base.html before:

```
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

And after:

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Small mistake that will hopefully save you 30 minutes of work. Check everything.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, make sure you load Jquery before any scripts.
You can place it on HTML head tag